# How to access a different parent of a model's child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding a feature to an old app that was not made by me, this along with being relatively new to RoR is leading to some confusion for me.

I have models called `reponse`, `activity_point`, and `report`

`response` has two parents, it belongs_to `activity_point` and `report`.

I am trying to access `activity_points` for a do block like so:

```
report.responses.activity_points.activity.each do |a|
```

Obviously that isn't working. I am getting the error message:

```
undefined method `activity_points' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this little problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can add something like this to your Report model

```
has_many :responses
has_many :activity_points, :through => :responses
has_many :activities, :through => :activity_points
```

then you can do this

```
report.activities.each do |a|
```

Another way to do this kind of thing, add a method to Report and joins from the other side (to get activity objects)

```
def activities
  Activity.joins(:activity_points => :responses).where('responses.report_id = ?', id)
end
```

The point of doing all this, you don't want to create Ruby objects if you don't need to.  Nested loops are also a potential problem with unique items and sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Each `response` have several `activity_points` so you should iterate through `responses`. Also each `activity_point` has several `activities`, so:

```
report.responses.each do |r|
  r.activity_points.each do |ap|
    ap.activity.each do |a|
      # Do your thing
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when you write `report.responses`, this will return an `ActiveRecord array`. Since `activity_points` is an undefined method for `arrays`, you can't call it. So to call this method there is two conditions:

1. You have to tell your app which element of the array will call the method. For instance, `report.responses.first.activity_points` or `report.responses.second.activity_points` ...
2. `Response` model has to have a `has_many: activity_points` to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could still also use a loop, but that will take multiple DB calls. Therefore, my solution involves direct database call for efficiency.

```
Activity.includes(activity_point: {responses: :report}).where(reports: {id: report.id}).each do |a|
  #...
  #...
end
```